# Github action: failed to build spring boot project

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, github

Github action is throwing a exception on build phase, the problem is that it's saying can not connect to database(MySQL) I tried to change bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 in MySQL configuration and none solved the problem I don't really know whereis the trick.
I'm using that for sonarcloud to analyze automatically.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the GitHub actions, not self-hosted, they have no way to connect to your local sonar database.

I think you have a couple options:

1. Deploy a self-hosted runner on the same host as the sonar DB
2. Make the sonar publicly available and provide the public URL to the GitHub action config